# Azure Stream analytics : Iot Hub to sql database : No output - degraded

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, esp8266, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I sent json format from Esp8266 to iot hub but I can't send data from iot hub to sql database by Stream Analytics

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I test query in Stream Analytics job, it's ok but I run Stream Analytics job data can't record to sql database and informed that "degraded"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your job may not have the correct permissions to the SQL database.

I suggest configuring a Managed Identity for your Stream Analytics job and using that to create a user with the required permissions in Azure SQL DB as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-database-output-managed-identity?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&tabs=azure-sql)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions.